# how I can set my port in forwarding on a udp connection?

Tags: c#, udp, connection

I want to create a UDP connection between my computer and another computer so that my port is 8000 and the destination port is 8000. Then I can send and receive packets on the connection. My problem is that I can not specify my own port and a random port is created for sending.

```
IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint (DesIp, 8000);
UdpClient udpSender = new UdpClient();
udpSender.Connect(endpoint);

IPAddress Client = IPAddress.Parse("MyIp");
endpoint = new IPEndPoint (Client, 8000);
UdpClient udpListener = new UdpClient();
udpListener.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
udpListener.Client.Bind(endpoint );
```

In listening mode, I receive packets on my 8000 port from another 8000 computer port. But when I want to send a packet, a random port is created as a sender on my system and I send it to the port of 8000 destinations. I want my port in the sending mode to be 8000 as well.
It is possible to have a listening or forwarding mode enabled at any time.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to spend a little time checking the documentation for [UdpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient), wou will notice that it is indeed possible to specify a local port which the UdpClient binds to: [`public UdpClient (int localPort)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.-ctor?view=net-6.0#System_Net_Sockets_UdpClient__ctor_System_Int32_).